# PHP MySQL: Updating users profile

Tags: php, mysql

I got a problem for my profile page in my login system. When I want to update the user's username and email, I can only update one of the two. Look where I putted the points. If I use username it only updates the username and the same goes for the email.

Here is my code:

```
function updateProfile($db, $errors)
{       
    $id = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);   
    $field_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' email='$email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $field_check_query);
    $field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    // Checks if username is already taken
    if ($field) { 
        if ($field['username'] === $username) {
          array_push($errors, "Gebruikersnaam is al reeds ingenomen");
        }       
        // Checks if email is already taken
        if ($field['email'] === $email) {
            array_push($errors, "E-mailadres is al reeds ingenomen");
        }
    }

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        if (isset($_POST['.......'])) {
            $query = "UPDATE users SET username='$username' email='$email' WHERE id=$id";
            mysqli_query($db, $query);
            header('location: profile.php?profileeditedsuccesfully');
            die($query);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the SQL queries even work? To me it seems as if the `SELECT` misses an `AND` (or `OR`) and the `UPDATE` misses a comma.

Comment: It did work, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `AND` to WHERE in Select:

```
$field_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND email='$email'";
```

Add comma to separate the pairs in Update.

```
=$query = "UPDATE users SET username='$username', email='$email' WHERE id=$id";
```